# Indicar datos en grafico de barras con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gráficas

Estoy trabajando con una tabla que indica el Número del día, la hora del día y un número de visitas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero crear un gráfico de barras que indique el número de visitas por cada hora (como el de la imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, ¿cómo puedo indicar también las horas en cada barra? Algo similar a esto que he hecho con el paint, pero en todas las horas, claro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) o también [`matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) para añadir el texto que quieras sobre cada columna.

Supongo que tus datos están en un DataFrame de Pandas, por lo que puedes usar [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) para facilitar la creación del gráfico a partir del mismo, aunque la idea es la misma si se usa `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` directamente.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



data = {"Dia": (14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12),
        "Hora": (16, 14, 13, 12, 23, 22, 21, 20),
        "Visita": (5, 2, 6, 19, 8, 47, 13, 51)}

visitsPerDay = pd.DataFrame(data)
ax = visitsPerDay.plot.bar("Dia", "Visita")

for i, bar in enumerate(ax.patches):
    ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, bar.get_height() + 1.5,
            f"{visitsPerDay['Hora'][i]}:00",
            horizontalalignment= 'center', verticalalignment='bottom',
            fontsize=10, rotation=90, color='dimgrey')

ax.set_xlabel("Número del dia")
ax.set_ylabel("Visitas")
ax.margins(x=0, y=0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dado que aparentemente la hora la representas como un entero, he usado simplemente formateo de literales de cadena `f"{visitsPerDay['Hora'][i]}:00"` para asignar la cadena correspondiente a cada barra , si usas Python < 3.6 puedes usar `"{}:00".format(visitsPerDay['Hora'][i])`.